# How to filter by territory name in Lightning Experience dashboard?

Tags: lightning-experience, dashboard, filters, territory-management

I have a dashboard that contains a report, which deals with accounts and territories (Enterprise Territory Management).

I would like to add a dashboard filter for territory name, also known as label. If I modify the dashboard and click '+ filter', the only territory fields I can filter by, are Last modified date and Last modified by. Not label.

Can I filter by territory label, and if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully re-reading the Salesforce help page about this ([Help on dashboard filters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dashboard_filters_editing.htm&type=5)), I found the solution myself. The relevant section is:

> From the Field drop-down, select a field to filter on. The drop-down
>   shows fields that can be used to filter all the dashboard’s
>   components.

And the important word there is: all. I had two components in the dashboard, one that used territory fields and one that didn't. After I had deleted the component without territory fields, the drop down for possible filter fields showed all territory fields, including the name.